# Get stream from urlsessiondownloadtask

Tags: ios, swift, stream

When we use URLSessionDownloadTask for downloading files there temp file where is data saved by chunks.
Is there any way to save data chunks not on disk and store it in memory?
Or is there any way to modify the data stream?
The problem is I need to encrypt all data in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `URLSessionDownloadTask`, you could use `URLSessionDataTask`, which allows you to handle incoming data by chunks. This way, you can encrypt the data as it's being received and then write it to disk or keep it in memory.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/file")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        // Encrypt the data here
        let encryptedData = encrypt(data)
        
        // Do something with encryptedData
        // ...
    }
}
task.resume()
```

If you can't avoid using `URLSessionDownloadTask`, another approach would be to wait until the download is complete and the temporary file is created. Then, read the file, encrypt it, and save the encrypted data back to disk. This approach may not be suitable if you're dealing with large files or have strict security requirements that mandate on-the-fly encryption.

Comment: *"This approach may not be suitable if you're dealing with large files"* - if the files are too large, then doing it all in memory will likely be a bigger issue.

Comment: @HangarRash you absolutely right. This another side of coin.